# Cannot find module '../drop-file.js' protractor, angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, module, protractor

I'm trying to use a module ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547182/simulate-drag-and-drop-of-file-to-upload-in-protractor)) in **protractor**, in a **angular 9 app** but i'm not able to and get the following error :
 `Error: Error: Cannot find module './drop-file.js'`

The error say that it doesn't find the module but the module is correcly called as you can see  bellow.

my structure :

```
drop-file.js
test.po.ts
```

*test.po.ts :*

```js
const dropFile = require('./drop-file.js');
export class ReviewPo {
...
  public uploadFiles() {
    ...
          dropFile(dropElement, './image.png');
    ...
  }
}
```

*drop-file.js :*

```js
"use strict";

var fs = require('fs');

var path = require('path');

var JS_BIND_INPUT = function JS_BIND_INPUT(target) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'file';
  input.style.display = 'none';
  input.addEventListener('change', function () {
    target.scrollIntoView(true);
    var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect(),
      x = rect.left + (rect.width >> 1),
      y = rect.top + (rect.height >> 1),
      data = {
        files: input.files
      };
    ['dragenter', 'dragover', 'drop'].forEach(function (name) {
      var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
      event.initMouseEvent(name, !0, !0, window, 0, 0, 0, x, y, !1, !1, !1, !1, 0, null);
      event.dataTransfer = data;
      target.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
    document.body.removeChild(input);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  return input;
};


module.exports = function (dropArea, filePath) {
  // get the full path
  filePath = path.resolve(filePath); // assert the file is present

  fs.accessSync(filePath, fs.F_OK); // resolve the drop area

  return dropArea.getWebElement().then(function (element) {
    // bind a new input to the drop area
    browser.executeScript(JS_BIND_INPUT, element).then(function (input) {
      // upload the file to the new input
      input.sendKeys(filePath);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In tsconfig.json, add

```
{
  ...

  "allowJs": true,

  ...
}
```

Now in test.po.ts

```
const dropFile = require('./drop-file');
```

Source: [How to import js-modules into TypeScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219542/how-to-import-js-modules-into-typescript-file)